# What happens to SQLite file after a failed Core Data migration?

Tags: ios, core-data

If a core data migration fails because it lacks a model mapping and throws up
`CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A887A5A9-BF8E-4678-8F19-465B858A424A/Documents/fiji-sql-v1 options:{`.

Later on the error message reads `!!Unable to migrate store!! — {....... lots of entities and hash values later... NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        "Version 15.0"
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "CDC37692-901E-4A6A-B2B2-D3A5C48AE03F";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;`

My new version is 16.0, the old is 15.0. Im wondering if its possible to still access the old core data model and map it, or is that file already overwritten or deleted.

EDIT: Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/IoDmitri/91466db7f1ff7e1285cb) to the full error

Here is my Core data options

```
NSDictionary *sqliteOptions =
@{
    @"synchronous" : @"0",
    @"fullfsync" : @"0"
};

//
//lightweight migrations are handled here
//
NSDictionary *options = 
    @{
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
        NSSQLitePragmasOption: sqliteOptions
    };
```

Comment: Obviously, this would not be documented, so what prevents you from trying it and checking out the files?

Comment: I looked through the documents folder within the device viewer and I only see one set of SQLite files with the DB name, Im wondering if the old DB is cached somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to have the entire error message. However, the first step when loading a persistent store is to compare the model hash in the store with the model hash of the current model and see if they match. If they don't match...

- If you specified automatic migration, Core Data attempts to do so, first by looking at the model to see if migration is possible.
- If you didn't specify automatic migration, Core Data looks for a model mapping based on the version hashes.

If a mapping model is needed but does not exist, Core Data gives up and leaves the persistent store alone. The persistent store should be unchanged, since there was no information describing how to change it. So your data **probably** has not changed, but without the full error message it's hard to be certain.

Comment: check my edit, Ive included my migration options and a gist with the full error.